# asp.net mvc c# tooltip

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

what is the best and most simplest way to create tooltip text  for textboxes

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-beautiful-tooltips-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JavaScript and probably with a framework like jQuery that fits very well with ASP.NET MVC. Using the framework means that someone's alread done the hard work and written a plugin for it!

- [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)
- [tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)
- [List of some tooltip plugins](https://www.jqueryscript.net/tooltip/)

There is of course the `title` attribute on text inputs that shows as a popup tip in some browsers.

Comment: I'm very disappointed that there is no integrated tool-tip in razor html for MVC... back to javascript again... Ho by the way, your first link is broken

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be the simplest and easy to maintain approach:

1. Create description using data annotation for the property of your model
   Example:

   `[Display(Name="MyTextBox", Description = "Title for your entry")]
   public string MyTextBox{ get; set; }`
2. Then in your view access the description above using:

   `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyTextBox, new { title = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(model => model.MyTextBox, ViewData ).Description })`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the title tag :

```
<input type="text" title="Hello I'm the tool-tip"/>
```

Mvc way :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.NameOfCustomer, new{ title= "Hello I'm the tool-tip" })
```

It's not fully customizable as is, but it does not require extra javascript nor a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data annotations on your model to put the tooltip in the Description property of the DisplayAttribute.

Then write your own Html Helper function that puts the Description property into the title attribute of the TextBox input field. You can call the helper TextBoxWithTooltipFor

In your view definition you can then replace the call to @(Html.TextBoxFor(...)) with the call to @(Html.TextBoxWithTooltipFor(...))

Here is the code that is tested and works.
[image: Picture of code to add tooltip to textbox]

Comment: Hi, you should use Stackoverflow code mechanics to show your code, like the way others do, or else your code cannot be copied and is hard to read